# Jenkins Pipeline Form JSON workload for CURL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying cURL inside jenkins pipeline along with data. The CURL command are as follows

```
sh(script:'curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "token":"swqkm7f55v39g9kkdggkzs","duration":10, "platform":"android", "available_now":"true"}' https://device.pcloudy.com/api/devices'
```

The problem here is in data token field, I would like to pass environmental variable. For say
I have vairable(env.authtoken) there I stored my token. This token need to be passed in curl

```
sh(script:'curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "token":"${env.authtoken}","duration":10, "platform":"android", "available_now":"true"}' https://device.pcloudy.com/api/devices',returnStdout: true)
```

But, it is telling unexpected character error. Actually, I would like to execute the statement as exactly same below

```
sh(script:"curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "token":"swqkm7f55v39g9kkdggkzs","duration":10, "platform":"android", "available_now":"true"}' https://device.pcloudy.com/api/devices"
```

Instead of hardcoded value in token field, I would like to pass my variable. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there is something wrong with the quotation marks. Try using a multi-line sh command in this manner:

```
sh """
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "token":"${env.authtoken}","duration":10, "platform":"android", "available_now":"true"}' https://device.pcloudy.com/api/devices
"""
```

See if the curl command goes through. If it does, then you can go back to your original command try to modify that so the quotes don't end up terminating the command prematurely. I'm guessing the problem lies in the fact that you start the command with `'` and use it again after `-d`. This breaks the curl command.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `''` to construct the command as string, then you've to escape the rest of `'` if you want to use it inside.

The same occurs if you use `""` to construct the string, then it's necessary to escap de `"`.

In both cases [escape it with a backslash](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_escaping_special_characters) before: `\'` or `\"`

In your first case for example:

```
sh(script:'curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \'{ "token":"swqkm7f55v39g9kkdggkzs","duration":10, "platform":"android", "available_now":"true"}\' https://device.pcloudy.com/api/devices')
```

Alternatively you can try with Groovy [multi line string](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_single_quoted_string) `'''yourmultilinestring'''` or [multi line gstring](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_double_quoted_string) if you want also to evaluate some variables `"""yourmultilinestring and ${somevariable}"""`, since in these cases it's not necessary to escape the single or double quotes.

A full working sample for your case:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    environment {
        authtoken = 'swqkm7f55v39g9kkdggkzs'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Stage - Test curl') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh(
                    script:"""
                    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "token":"${env.authtoken}","duration":10, "platform":"android", "available_now":"true"}' https://device.pcloudy.com/api/devices
                    """)
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```